# Antlr 3 Java if Statement within Grammar

Tags: if-statement, normalization, antlr3

Im tring to normalise an Antlr AST with Java Code.

What im tring to do is

> 7 – 2 = 5 converted to 5 + 2 = 7

I created the following grammar already

```
start   
    : (n1=NUMBER a=ARITME^ n2=NUMBER) e=EQUALS^ n3=NUMBER {if (String.valueOf($a)=="-") /*s.th*/ ;} ;

NUMBER      
    : '0'..'9';
ARITME      
    : '+'|'-';
EQUALS  
    : '=';
```

but im not sure how to re-set the values of n1, n2 and n3 (and change the "-" to a "+") to get displayed within the AST

Comment: You want to rewrite the tree already during the parsing process? I wouldn't do that. It is much more flexible to just create the AST as usual and then use a tree walker to examine the tree and create normaized output.

Comment: @MikeLischke thx ok I see, but is it possible to rewrite it during the parsing process? the normalization is the only thing I need to do here, so a walker seams a bit to much for this...